# rc.local не срабатывает при первом включении системы. Работает только после reboot

Tags: linux, автозагрузка, orange-pi

Записал скрипты для автозагрузки в rc.local, но они запускаются только после reboot т.е. если я выключу OrangePi и снова включу, то система запустится, а скрипты не запускаются, приходится выполнить reboot и тогда всё запускается.
1)Как это исправить?
2)Cтоит ли для этого использовать rc.local или для автозагрузки скриптов есть какие-то варианты получше?

OrangePi
OS Armbian без графической оболочки.

Содержимое rc.local:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
sleep 5
/usr/sbin/runScript6
/usr/sbin/runScript5
/usr/sbin/runScript4
/usr/sbin/runScript3
/usr/sbin/runScript2
/usr/sbin/runScript1
/usr/sbin/runScript0
exit 0
```

Пример содержимого одного скрипта:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
/usr/bin/python3 /mnt/telegramBot/bot.py&
```

Comment: "... или для автозагрузки скриптов есть какие-то варианты получше?" - Учитывая, что Вы его в бэкграунд отправляете, я б на Вашем месте написал для него init/unit-скрипт и запускал бы его как обычный демон при загрузке системы.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. скрипт оболочки в файле `/etc/rc.local` — один из множества запускаемых при загрузке операционной системы скриптов. искусственно тормозить процесс загрузки, вставляя в этот скрипт задержки типа `sleep интервал` — не стоит.
2. в нормальной ситуации скрипт `/etc/rc.local` должен завершить свою работу. поэтому если добавляемые вами в него команды не являются какими-нибудь быстро выполняющимися атомарными действиями, их следует завершать не оператором `;` (или его синонимом — символом новой строки), а оператором `&`, благодаря чему предшествующая оператору команда начнёт выполняться в «фоновом» процессе оболочки (*in the background in a subshell*), не задерживая выполнение следующей команды в основном процессе оболочки:

   ```
   команда параметры &
   команда параметры &
   ...
   ```
3. убедиться в том, выполняется ли вообще скрипт оболочки из файла `/etc/rc.local`, элементарно — достаточно где-нибудь ниже первой строки (с [шебангом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29)), но **до** добавленных вами команд, вставить строку с командой вроде `touch /tmp/somefile`, и после загрузки убедиться, что файл `/tmp/somefile` действительно был создан.